# my moto g, 2nd generation (XT1068) got stuck in a boot loop, not going past the motorola logo. How to solve this problem?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola, motorola-moto-g2

My motorola device keeps restarting with a specific interval and off again after showing the motorola logo screen.I have tried to reset my device but the device is much unresponsive.[Used this article for instructions](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/99825/p/30%2C6720%2C9151/kw/reset%20device) . The instructions are not clear in this article.

Comment: what changed that when it rebooted it started in this bootloop?

Comment: @RyanConrad While i was transfering a file to my device though usb, the transfer got stuck and when i tried to access my device, it was unresponsive. So i started pressing the power button a couple of times, and then is see the device was rebooting, but only upto the motorola logo (+ android logo)screen with a vibrate (which usually happens while booting). Then off, then again the logo screen, this goes on, till now, but the interval between the restarts have increased.

Comment: were you able to boot in to the Recovery? This is where you need to go to do a factory reset.

Comment: @RyanConrad No. When i select recovery option the normal logo screen appears like when trying to boot normally, the only option which works on flashboot menu is bar code, others when selected have the same behaviour! The automatic restart loop has now stopped but still can't boot up the device.